# What's the difference between using PostGIS functions and operators?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

PostGIS offers a list of [operators](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/reference.html#Operators) implementing spatial relations. Some of them have a direct function equivalent, for example `<->` and `ST_Distance`.

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT
st_distance(st_setsrid(st_makepoint(0, 0), 4326),
             st_setsrid(st_makepoint(10, 10), 4326))
```

and

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT
st_setsrid(st_makepoint (0, 0), 4326) <->
st_setsrid(st_makepoint (10, 10), 4326)
```

yield the exact same query plan. Are there any scenarios in which one method is preferable to the other?

Comment: Operators seem to utilize bounding boxes and thus <-> and ST_Distance are not equivalent for other geometries than points. Operators suit well for fast, spatial index spaced filtering. Typical use case is to make a fast pre-selection with && and run the slower but accurate ST_Intersects for the result set if it is important to know if the geometries really intersect.

Comment: that is not true for postgreSQL > 9.5:  `For PostgreSQL below 9.5 only gives centroid distance of bounding boxes and for PostgreSQL 9.5+, does true KNN distance search giving true distance between geometries, and distance sphere for geographies. `

Comment: Seems to require also PostGIS version 2.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`<->`](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html) and [`<#>`](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/geometry_distance_box.html) can make use of indexes when used in `SORT BY` clause.

> Used in the "ORDER BY" clause provides index-assisted nearest-neighbor result sets.

e.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1, table2
SORT BY table1.geom <-> table2.geom
LIMIT 1
```

See the example on the [docs for `<->`](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html).

Another difference:

`<->` *always* uses spherical distance for `geography` type, while [`st_distance`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html) uses distance calculated on a spheroid (slower) as default with an option to change it (`use_spheroid=false`).

Comment: What is the reasoning for `<->` to not use the spheroid?

Comment: @No_name -- *Speed*